# urlretrieve stopping at 4k

Tags: python, https, urllib

I'm using a script to download images from a website and up until recently it has been working fine. Of note the page is https, but per the urllib docs that shouldn't be an issue. It first requests the page and uses a regex to pull the download links from the page. From there the script goes into a loop to download the file and the inner loop looks like so:

```
dllink = m[0].replace('\">Download','')
print dllink
#m = re.findall('[a-f0-9]+.[\w]+',dllink)
extension = re.findall('.[\w]+$',dllink)[0]
fname = post_id + extension
urllib.urlretrieve(dllink,cpath + "/" + fname)
printLine(post_id + " ")
delay = random.uniform(32.0,64.0)
dlcount = dlcount + 1
time.sleep(delay)
```

Again, it downloads a file, but the files I'm downloading are on the order of 200k-4m and every file has started returning 4k.  I've copy-pasted the download links into browsers and it pulls the right image and wget also downloads it just fine, so I'm not sure what's wrong with my code where it's only downloading 4k of the file. If this is a server side issue is there a way to call wget from python to accomplish the same thing without urlretreive? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I doubt it is server side since your browser and wget do the right thing. Have you looked for other people encountering this issue?

Comment: I have, seems pretty specific and am either the only one running into this or I'm not savy enough with the search term to find similar issues.. Also the code was working up until now and I'm not sure if it was an update on my end or what.

Comment: FWIW, weirdities happen to us all, and debugging them can be a b*tch. A couple of days ago I had a problem that was driving me *nuts!* I have 3 subdomains pointing at my home IP address via DDNS. Two I use on a regular basis, the other one I had forgotten about. Six days ago one of the ones I use stopped working--unreachable from any place on the net and I couldn't figure out why. Packet filters, ISP blocking, firewalls, all of them checked clean. Eventually I compared the 3 IPs. Bingo! Turned out that my Comcast IP had changed and only 1 subdomain updated correctly. Sigh. I hate computers.

Comment: I'd expect this is just down to buffer scaling. At first it is unclear how large the stream is, so it just gets the headers and possibly some data. Then from the headers it can extract the data size and scales the buffer to the right size.